# Which file system best handle multiple, concurrent write sessions

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, xfs, gfs2

Which file system best handle multiple, concurrent write sessions

Which file system can handle more concurrent write sessions; let’s say 32 write sessions?

The file system has to handle 32 concurrent sessions with each session writing 100Mb uncompressed data file in 5 minutes. Please suggest

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I believe I corrected the question which was confusing earlier.

Comment: @JijoJohn: your re-written question is now a product recommendation which also off-topic. Your IO requirements are very simple 32 x 100 MB in 300 seconds equals storing 10 MB/s in a more-or-less sequential writes, something even a slow 5400 rpm laptop drive can accommodate easily. With simple IO patterns the disks become a limiting factor long before the choice of file-system makes any difference. Using compression like ewwhite proposes reduces the amount of data that needs to be stored making things quicker and my tempfs also cheats and stores all data in memory rather than on (slow) disk.

Answer (score 4):

ZFS with lz4 compression is pretty quick, depending on the compressibility of the data.

But the rest of the items you're comparing aren't actually comparable. You've listed cluster filesystems, network filesystems, caching layers, and traditional filesystems.

Answer (score 3):

No contest, [tmpfs](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/7fs/tmpfs/) !

> tmpfs is designed as a performance enhancement ...